# Google map v3 custom... v2 was easy... v3 kinda mess

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'd like to rebuild a map with the same gestures as this one buily by http://marcgrabanski.com/ using the V2 api.

http://assets.marcgrabanski.com/resources/jquery-google-maps/tutorial-part1.html

But I would like to use the V3 API. But I feel the v3 is more, maybe unnecessarily, complicated and I would like to find a working example to start built in v3.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To demonstrate gmaps api v3, I've just put up a small example for you [here](http://tallymobile.com/test4.html). This is just off-the-cuff code based on the example you have mentioned in your post. Just enter the co-ordinates to add the markers on to map and then select the specific marker to display the info window.

The main parts of the code are

**Creation of the map**

```
function initialize(){
var myOptions = {
zoom: 14,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.0, 62.0),
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                            myOptions);

infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
                { 
                    size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
                });

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.close();
    });

markersArray = [];
```

}

**Creating the markers**

```
    function createMarker(latlng, html,zoom) {
   var contentString = html;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });
    marker.MyZoom = zoom; 
    return marker; 
}
```

The google maps api v3 is far better designed and you can check out some other samples  [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/index.html).

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should use the official examples that Google actually provides: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html